# ability to choose what to be included in a generated rmarkdown report from shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

In a shiny framework that I am using, the user has the ability to generate reports directly from the shiny with different format types(pdf, HTML, word). There is a textAreaInput() where you can write a description for the reprot and if there is no description, the report will still be generated due to the following code in rrmarkdown.

```
{r, results='asis',echo=F}
if(nchar(params$description) > 1){ # If there was a description specified, add it to the report
cat('\n**Description:**\n')
cat(input$description)
}
```

There is also the possibility to generate plots, and if there is no plot generated in the shiny, then the report won't be rendered and it will give an error since there is no "graph()"

```
{r 2 plot, echo=FALSE, fig.cap= 'Plot 1}
graph()
```

So my question is, is there something similar to "if(nchar())" for reactive function so even if there is no generated plot, the rest of the report will still be rendered?
thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: [This](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/2671/Combining-Shiny-R-Markdown.html) should give you all you need.

Comment: @Limey Thank you! But it does not touch upon the specific subject at all